# ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I got a lot of this error on my logs in a site hosting

> ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Partial results are valid but
>   processing is incomplete [hostname "www.example.com"] [uri
>   "/index.php"] [unique_id "VoOZ-YBBwycAAN3ShrIAAAA2"]

Is anybody know how to workaround or fix those errors please?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Joomla 2.5 or Joomla 3.0 ?

Comment: we are using joomla 3.4.8 latest version.

Comment: Then why is your question tagged with Joomla 2.5

Comment: Because i am facing this error in joomla 2.5 and after updating joomla 3.0 in both cases.